# Is it possible to write a program that writes code depending on conditions in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
def method1
  join_tables = [:table1, :table2, :table3]
  query_params = { "users.phone" => @mobile_number, "user_email" => @email}
  user_query_condition = create_query_or_union(user_query_params)   // returns "users.phone = 99999999 OR user_email = example@example.com"
  return previous_query(join_tables, user_query_condition)
end

def method2
  join_tables = [:table1]
  query_params = { "users_email" => @email }
  user_query_condition = create_query_or_union(user_query_params)
  return live_query(join_tables, user_query_condition)
end
```

I have multiple methods like this and worse, some methods contain two similar queries as  well. Only, the `query_params` and returning function calls vary.

So, I was thinking putting all this code into a function which can write the code depending upon the input params. For example,

I would call result = `awesome_method(join_tables, query_params, "live")` and that would be it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You don't even need code that writes code. You just need one generic method, that accepts parameters, instead of having stuff hardcoded. Avoid metaprogramming as long as you can, it's a slippery slope :)

Comment: It's definitely possible to do metaprogramming in Ruby. In fact, I am quite surprised that you haven't come across it yet. For example, there is a method called `attr_accessor` which writes getter and setter methods depending on the name(s) of the instance variables passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with a bit of metaprogramming in Ruby, it is good for cases like this where you have repetitive methods. Aside from eliminating duplication it can also give you a better overview of what all your different queries are, something like this:

```
METHODS = {
           method1: {tables: [:table1, :table2, :table3],
                     params: {"users.phone" => @mobile_number, "user_email" => @email}},
           method2: {tables: [:table1],
                     params: { "users_email" => @email },
                     live: true},
          }

METHODS.each do |method, params|
  define_method method do
    join_tables = params[:tables]
    query_params = params[:params]
    user_query_condition = create_query_or_union(query_params)   // returns "users.phone = 99999999 OR user_email = example@example.com"
    if params[:live]
      return live_query(join_tables, user_query_condition)
    else
      return previous_query(join_tables, user_query_condition)
    end
  end
end
```